# How to store Numpy array in Cassandra as blob?

Tags: python, numpy, cassandra

I have a column defined as `blob` type and I'd like to store `numpy` arrays in it.

So far I have this:

```
out = io.BytesIO()
np.save(out, np.array([1.0,2.0]))
out.seek(0)

session.execute("""
INSERT INTO table(blob_value) 
    VALUES (%s)
    """ , (out.read(),))
```

Is this the way to go?